# update custom post custom field value when post is saved in wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

How to update custom post custom field value when post is saved in admin?

I have tried to use this in misc.php for admin section:

```
add_action('pre_post_update', 'do_something_with_a_post');
function do_something_with_a_post($id) {

    global $post;
    update_post_meta($id, 'ct_Course_Dur_text_d19c', 'test12');

)
```

But it is not working.

Comment: you mean your custom field values arnt saving on save post ?

Answer (score 4):

You may try this (Using [save_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook), paste this code in your `functions.php` file

```
function save_cpt_metadata($id, $post)
{
    if($post->post_type != 'your_custom_post_type') {
        return;
    }
    update_post_meta($id, 'ct_Course_Dur_text_d19c', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['your_custom_field'] ) );
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_cpt_metadata');
```

In this example `sanitize_text_field( $_POST['your_custom_field'] )` is would be actually the cstom field on your form but you may use any hard coded data, replace the `your_custom_post_type` with your real custom post type.